# RoR: Check boxes in form_for for has_many, :through with a Join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

Once again, I have my `form_for` for my `Order` model, which `has_many :services, :through => :requests`.  Here's the layout of how I have my relationships mapped:

```
 __________                               _________
| Customer |                             | Utility |
 ----------                               ---------
   ||   ^                                     /\
   ||   |                                     ||
   \/   |                                     /\
   _______           _________             _________
  | Order | <=====< | Request |  >=====>  | Service | 
   -------           ---------             ---------
                                              \/
                                              ||
                                              \/
                                           _________  
                                          | Company |
                                           ---------
```

Where:

```
--->                    = belongs_to
===>                    = has_many
<==< join model >==>    = has_many, :through
```

On my Order form, I want to have an array of checkboxes that represent the services available, such that even though the checkboxes are labelled by the `Company` and categorized by `Utility`, the `Order` ends up with the `Service` association when the order is complete (because that's really what the customer is ordering: a Company to provide a Utility, which is a Service).

How do I accomplish this in my form?

---

**form view:**

```
- form_for @order do |order_form| 
  -# order form inputs, etc.
  - order_form.fields_for :customer do |customer_form| 
    -# customer form inputs
  - order_form.fields_for :services do |services_form| 
    %dl
      - @services.each do |service_name, services| 
        %dt= service_name
        - services.each do |service_item| 
          %dd
            =# check_box ??????????
            =# label ??????????, Company.find(service_item.company_id).name
  %p= order_form.submit 'Create Order'
```

Where:

```
@services = Service.all.to_set.classify { |service_item| Utility.find(service_item.utility_id).name }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Railscast on [HABTM checkboxes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes) -- it's an oldie but goodie. I'm pretty sure it should still work even with a join model.

Comment: If only all of life's problems could be solved by Ryan Bates's Railscasts... that would be the life. Thanks; this is exactly what I needed!